# I have a problem with my javascript menu icon (scratch)

Tags: javascript, css, menu, font-awesome

So I'm building a portfolio website but I have a problem with the icon menu, when I click on it nothing happen.

I tried replacing the fontawesome icon with a image, asking chatgpt(yeah i know), calling id then class again I'm a little lost.

Here is the code:

html

```
<header>
        <img src="assets/img/blanclogo.png" class="logo" alt="logo-blanc">
            <nav>
                <ul class="navlist" id="navlist">
                    <li><a href="#home" title="Accueil" class="active">Accueil</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#logiciel" title="Mes logiciels">Mes compétences</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#portfolio" title="Page liste portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="assets/pdf/CV.pdf" title="CV">CV</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#contact" title="formulaire">Me contacter</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </nav>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-bars" id="menu-burger"></i>  
</header>
```

javascript

```
const header = document.querySelector('header');
const menuBurger = header.querySelector('#menu-burger');
const navList = header.querySelector('#navlist');

menuBurger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  menuBurger.classList.toggle('active');
  navList.classList.toggle('active');
});

navList.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener('click', () => {
    menuBurger.classList.remove('active');
    navList.classList.remove('active');
  });
});
```

Comment: No i have the last version of fontawesome taken on cdjns (all.min.js)

Answer (score 0):

If you want replace the menu icon by an X, you can do that on your code:

```
menuBurger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (menuBurger.classList.contains('fa-bars')) {
        menuBurger.classList.replace('fa-bars', 'fa-xmark');
    } else {
        menuBurger.classList.replace('fa-xmark', 'fa-bars');
    }
    navList.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

In the IF you check if the icon class contains "fa-bars" with this function: `contains("fa-bars")`. If it is true, then we replace the "fa-menu" with a "fa-xmark": `menuBurger.classList.replace('fa-bars', 'fa-xmark');`.
Otherwise, we do the reverse: `menuBurger.classList.replace('fa-xmark', 'fa-bars');`.

Say my if you have any problem and if that's what you need.